# Accessing Array Element with Char

Tags: java, arrays

I'm going through some Java exercises and happened upon this bit of code that I don't fully grok.

```
public static boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        int[] letters = new int[128];

        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        for (char c : s_array) {
            letters[c]++;
        }
        // omitted other code
}
```

When I print out the contents of `letters`, I see an array of integers.  Depending on the strings I pass into the function that array returns variations of `0`'s and `1`'s.

I thought that maybe the `Array` class was converting the `char` to an `int`.  I added a print statement to help but I see the value of `d` to be 13 yet I see the 13th element in the array still as `0`.  That code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word1 = "dog";
        String word2 = "god";
        permutation(word1, word2);
    }

    public static boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        int[] letters = new int[128];

        char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
        for (char c : s_array) {
            System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(c));
            letters[c]++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
13
24
16
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My question being what does `Array[char]` syntax translate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Character.getNumericValue` returns the character "interpreted" as a numeral. For example the character `'5'` becomes just `5`. This also works for unicode characters representing roman numerals for example, or for hexadecimal digits. (Hence `'d'` becomes `'13'`.)

However, when you use a `char` in a context where an integral value is expected, it is interpreted using its encoding. For example `'a'` has the code 97, so `array['a']` accesses the 98th element of `array`.

That's the reason for the discrepancy of your two outputs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

the code is counting letters in the input string `s`. You create letters as `new int[128]` so you can cover "normal" ASCII characters. Then `letters[c]++` is increasing the counter of char `c`. `char` can be used as `int` in Java, so `letters[c]` refers to `letters[<ASCII index of c>]`